# Upper bound equal to lower in Python range

Tags: python, python-3.x, range

Can someone please explain to me why this code works for 2 as well:

```
def is_prime_v1(n):
  '''Return True if 'n' is prime. False otherwise.'''
  if n == 1:
    return False

  for d in range(2,n):
    if n % d == 0:
      return False

  return True
```

when the code gets to

```
for d in range(2,n):
    if n % d == 0:
      return False
  return True
```

Would it not see this as start at 2 but go up to and do not include 2?
This does not make complete sense to me.
The formula works but if you try and create a list on that range like so:

```
x = list(range(2,2))
```

You get an empty list.

Please could anyone explain this to me? Does it work for two as well because it would not be able to do the below on range(2,2) and then moves down to return True?

```
 if n % d == 0:
      return False
  return True
```

Thanks

Comment: I mean, if it said `for d in []:`, would you be confused by the behaviour? Converting the range to a list doesn't change the number of elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because for loop is never executed ,  `list(range(2,2)) == []`, so the program didn't iterate over range and directly proced to `return True` statement

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption is correct. The upper value of the `range` function is not put through the `for` loop. To overcome this, you could just add `or n == 2` to the third line of your program.